# Is it possible to log all actions to script file in chrome or firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In chrome/firefox, we can click "inspect" or "inspect element" in the context menu.
Then we can select an element, delete, ...
I wondering if it is possible to log these actions to a js script file.
So I can reproduce it later

Comment: Not that I know, but if you want to do some modifications to a website and be able to repeat those actions, you can try with PuppeteerJs or Selenium. Not sure if you have already considered that option or if it suits your needs

Comment: @f-CJ Thanks. I will give it a try